# Android: Format date to only be date

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a date as Wed Feb 28 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2024

I would like to format this to be Wed Feb 28 00:00:00 2024

here is the current code

```
try {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", locale)
        dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC)
        dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date))
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        null
    }
```

This returns Tue Feb 27 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2024

locale is currently set to "en"

Comment: Are you aware that `java.util.Date` is a very old (and problematic) class that has been replaced more than 10 years ago by classes from the `java.time` package?

Comment: @k314159 I know, the application uses this throughout and I simply don't have enough time to rewrite it all.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code

```
    val dateStr = "Wed Feb 28 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2024"

// Define input date format
val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)

// Define output date format
val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)

try {
    // Parse the original date string
    val date = inputFormat.parse(dateStr)

    // Format the date to the desired format
    val formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date)

    println(formattedDate)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: In the question the date already is a `java.util.Date`. What is asked is how to format that date so it does not contain the timezone component.